# Manipulating elements in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am currently trying to learn basic web development, now starting with Vue on an online learning platform.

With this code below:

```
<div id="app">
      <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <input v-model="userName">
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
      </form>
      <div>{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
```

I want to make so that the internal `div`-element changes to "Hello" followed by what's in the text field(a name), followed by an "!" when you press enter

This is my Vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    message: null,
    userName: null
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function() {
      this.message = this.userName + '!'
    }
  }
})
```

The code doesn't work, and me two gives error outputs:

```
does not have an onSubmit method which renders the correct message for the value “John Smith” ***(just an example of a name)
does not has an onSubmit method which renders the correct message for some value
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the snippet below your code works perfectly. You joust need to add "Hello" before username and you get the result you want. The bot is complaining about the value returned by the onSubmit method, since it does not contain "Hello" in it.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    message: null,
    userName: null
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function() {
      this.message = "Hello " + this.userName + '!'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <input v-model="userName">
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
      </form>
      <div>{{ message }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I  made the changes to my code, but the bot still gives me the same output as before.

Comment: @left4read123 Sorry my friend, the problem is not with the code you posted

Comment: When I run the snippet, it works fine. But when I run the HTML with the JS file separately it does not act the way it should.